# Learn to comprehend distorted voices

Tags: listening

My English is something LinkedIn calls "Professional Working Proficiency". I was able to read and understand about any book I've came across, I write English daily and I usually have no issues talking general subjects to anyone.

Unless there is an echo, a wind or the voice is distorted otherwise. Then I'm nearly helpless. Phone calls from taxi drivers are a pain (even if we can easily chat during the trip), listening to notices in airports is too (albeit I don't get them easily even in my mother tongue, so perhaps this has more to do with physiology).

Are there any good ways to develop my audition skills, especially in "noisy" environments such as phone calls or airports?

Comment: I use a headset and English subtitles whenever I watch a movie to make sure I do not miss any word. This is after many decades of reading, speaking and listening to English at a very high level. I do NOT get what they say on the tannoy in any language either. My hearing is excellent.

Comment: Come to Philadelphia and try to understand the SEPTA announcements. It is the auditory counterpart of learning to orate with pebbles in your mouth.

Comment: Have you had a hearing test, specifically focusing on speech comprehension? That should come first. Other than confirming vocabulary/grammar skills, reading/writing ability are not really relevant to your question.

Answer (score 1):

I know where you're coming from; I speak Spanish and German to some proficiency, *except* when there are echoes or other conflicting noises.

My advice is to try to focus on the timing of English sentences.  It lacks the harsh consonants of German, or the predictable syllable patterns of Spanish, or the rounded vowels of French, but the timing is something you can rely upon.  Try to pick up the one stressed syllable per few words and latch on to the "beat" of the sentence.
Example: "I went downstairs to the research event."

- "went" and "re-" and "-vent" are stressed.  Ask a native speaker to say it out loud, and listen.  It's arbitrary, but what in this language isn't?

This message board talks about the subject: http://boards.straightdope.com/sdmb/showthread.php?t=563204